# How to fix Cannot find runner for main.dart with Flutter in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

During my development process, I faced an issue. I primarily used Android Studio for development. Can anyone assist me?

[image]

The error is that "Cannot find a runner for main.dart."

Set the Flutter SDK path.

Comment: Please dont mix question with answer, you can include on *answer* section and  check out [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, **follow the steps below**.

First, open your Android studio.

- go to **File -> Settings**.

[image]

- **Select Languages & Frameworks.**

[image]

[image]

- **Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter.**

[image]

- **Set Flutter SDK path.**

[image]

It works for me I would like to share it with you so that benefit prevails.

Hope this is helpful!